# How can I use the same sans-serif font for text and math

Tags: math-mode, fonts, sans-serif, math-fonts

I use ordinary text, math, figure and table environments and every letter in my document needs to be the same font style and font family (sans serif).

I already managed to make everything but the math environments in sf.

How can I do that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[format=plain,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,font={stretch=1.125,small,sf},labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \sffamily\everymath{\mathsf{}}
    \lispum[2]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Is there a general way to change all fonts at once?

Comment: Have you looked at the arev fonts?  http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/